# How to select a multiple field value by expression from the same layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, select-by-attribute

Using QGIS in the operation 'select by expression' how is the correct expression to select multiple field value? ex. City NAME = ROME and NAPLES (expression is invalid)

Comment: do you mean OR instead of AND?

Answer (score 33):

You can also use the SQL IN operator

```
"City Name" IN ('ROME','NAPLES')
```

Comment: Is it possible to do something similar but only stating part of the part of the words ? For example i would like to select all features containing 'RO' and 'PLES'. I tried IN but it doesn't works. I know that "City Name" LIKE '%RO%' OR "City Name" LIKE '%PLES%' works but the expression is a bit long... I would like something such as "City Name" LIKE ('%RO%','%PLES%').

Answer (score 10):

Do you mean:

```
"City Name" = 'ROME' OR "City Name" = 'NAPLES' OR ....
```

Comment: Just formatted the code so that it's valid QGIS expression code.

Comment: This won't actually return any results.  As the City Name can't both be ROME and Naples.  You want an or here, or use flippinGeo's answer and use "IN".

Comment: That's right, my mistake, you need to use OR, rather than AND