# QGIS selection multiple values by expression using number range

Tags: qgis

I would like to select about 20 objects by expression in QGIS. Their selection field is ID, which runs up to over 2000 items.
I need them over 20 in the specified range.
I found a nice way of doing it here:

[How to select a multiple field value by expression from the same layer in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78133/how-to-select-a-multiple-field-value-by-expression-from-the-same-layer-in-qgis)

but it seems like I have to include them one by one.

So far my code looks like this:

```
 BTOBJECTID IN ('1495','1496','1497','1498'.'1499','1500')
```

and includes just 1/4 of all items.

Is there any way to define the number range for this selection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `between` operator:

```
id  BETWEEN 1495 AND 1500
```

[image]